# display content only if site visitor clicks on atleast two ads

Tags: wordpress, adsense

On my site, i want to show certain hidden content to users only if user clicks on at least two google adsense ads.

so

1. is there any adsense policy which I might violate because of this
2. is it possible, if yes how?

I have never done development in php, but that wont be an issue.

P.S. I know various reasons why this will be a bad idea, but if i still want to do it, then how do I do it?

Comment: 1. don't know, but this is not the place to solve this 2. Yes this is possible, you have a huge field on possibilites. Hide the content, track the click events on ads and then show the content for example.

Comment: if you can please share some sample code on how to track click events on ads? or may be some blog which guides on how to do it

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: link of jquery documentation is not really the answer :(